WordPress Fatal error: Cannot declare class "Merlin" because the name is already in use
I recently faced this issue while trying to install wordpress theme "Electron"
and after installing it gave me bellow error
"wordpress Fatal error: Cannot declare class Merlin because the name is already in use"

And solution to this is
you have to disable plugin that is being used to add any theme or templates
in my case it was
"Themely"
